# xamarin.ios/monotouch facebook callback

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement login by facebook in a xamarin ios application,
Following an example from [monotouch-bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook/samples/FacebookSample)
I am checking if the user is logged in AppDelegate using this:

```
var sessionDelegate = new SessionDelegate (this); 
facebook = new Facebook (AppId, sessionDelegate);
if (facebook.IsSessionValid) {
    ShowLoggedIn ();
}
else
{
    ShowLoggedOut ();
}
```

The problem is that when the user is not logged in, I am navigating to another viewController in order for him to login. When he tries to Login the Facebook App opens, but after the login I am not getting the callback.
If I do the whole flow in AppDelegate, then the callback works.
I have noticed that in AppDelegate there are 2 overrides implemented:

```
public override bool HandleOpenURL
```

and

```
public override bool OpenUrl
```

They both return `return facebook.HandleOpenURL (url);`
facebook is declared in the AppDelegate but also in the login viewController, so I guess this is part of the problem.
I am new to iOS and mono touch, so i hope this make sense.
Any ideas how to solve it? or maybe an example where Facebook login is not performed from the AppDelegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent several hours this week aswell, trying to get it to work, and my problem was like yours. Yes you need to override OpenUrl, otherwise you won't be able to handle anything in the FBsession, which is why its not working for you.

so implement it as described in the scrumptious example, and it should work :) [Scrumptious](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/facebook/samples/Scrumptious/Scrumptious/AppDelegate.cs)

Comment: Yes, I know the override is needed. But how do I get a callback when trying to Login from another View (Not from the AppDelegate)?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? Dont you have a login viewcontroller?